# Call Web API within MVC Program

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I created Web API to receive daily temperature from OpenWeatherAPI.

Now I want to display everything on my MVC web page. I put the API  call in the MVC project; plan to create new project later for better microservice architecture.

I am seeing these errors in Debug windows and MVC html with following. How do I get weather, temperature, etc, precipitation, to display on html.

```
Debug: weathercontroller.City("Seattle")    The function evaluation requires all threads to run.    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>"

HTML: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult,WeatherChecker.Controllers.WeatherController+<City>d__0]"
```

**MVC Page:**

```
namespace WeatherPage.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public WeatherController weathercontroller = new WeatherController();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
            ViewData["test"] =  weathercontroller.City("Seattle");
            return View();
        }
```

**API Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/{city}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> City(string city)
    {

        Rootobject rawWeather = new Rootobject();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
                var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid=APIkey&units=metric");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(stringResult);
                return Ok(rawWeather);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
            }
        }
    }




public class Rootobject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
    public string _base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

**This works in my project:**
https://localhost:55555/api/weather/city/washington

[Retrieve Data From Third party Openweather Api](https://jonhilton.net/2017/01/24/retrieve-data-from-a-third-party-openweather-api-using-asp-net-core-web-api/)

[Should We Call Web Api from Mvc Application in Same Solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246380/should-we-call-web-api-from-mvc-application-in-same-solution)

Comment: Don't new up your API controller in this controller. Use `HttpClient` to make a request to the endpoint exposed by your API controller.

Comment: hi Chris, can you submit alternative solution, thought I was already using Http client in code, thanks

Comment: You are in your actual `WeatherController`, but in your `HomeController` you're attempting to simply just call the action like a method on an instance of `WeatherController`. You need to use `HttpClient` there as well. Also, don't new up `HttpClient` directly. It should be treated as a singleton. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an await statemant when your are calling your API Action.

Your code should be like this:

```
ViewData["test"] =  await weathercontroller.City("Seattle");
return View();
```

You need to change your controller to async so it can await a method and be read by system as an async method. Your code should look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
    ViewData["test"] = await weathercontroller.City("Seattle");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You need to go "asyc all the way".  The `About` action in your `HomeController` needs to be `async`: `public async Task<IActionResult> About()`

Comment: It's because you need to change your controller to async so it can await a method and be read by the system as an async method.

Your code should look like this:

`public async Task<IActionResult> About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
            ViewData["test"] =  weathercontroller.City("Seattle");
            return View();
        }
`

Comment: thanks, tried it and works, gave points, thumbs up if you like question also